# How to get utf8-encoded text from restfb

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, multilingual, restfb

i'm trying to fetch all posts and comments from a facebook's page using RestFB. All works, but when i try to fetch a russian page, that has particular chars, storing the result in mysql, every rows has some `?` and i understand that encoding isn't good.

So:

My table charset encoding is `utf8_general_ci`.

From RestFB i fetch feed from page in this way:

```
Connection<Post> pagePosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection(page+"/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("message", "utf8"));
```

but every comments stored in db is always something like:

```
Liels paldies Amerikas Tirdzniec?bas pal?tai un m?su burv?gajiem viesiem par br?niš??go pas?kumu!
```

How can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `jdbc` connection..

Solved in this way:

```
jdbc:mysql://server/database?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true
```